# Add dynamic parameter to DelegatingHandler used within the HttpClientFactory Service

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly, ihttpclientfactory, delegatinghandler

I'm trying to use a IHttpClientFactory in my application in order to efficiently manage the HTTP Clients used throughout its lifecycle.

Each of these clients need to have their bearer token set up depending on a specific Client ID which is only known at runtime (at any point we can have several Client IDs in use), so essentially this is a parameter I have to use to get the Authorization header. Because these headers expire frequently (something I have no control over when it will happen), I want to reset the Token Header and retrying the call on a 401 status response.

I tried using an HTTPClientService to create them which receives an IHTTPClientFactory through Dependency Injection:

```
    internal class HttpClientService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public HttpClientService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        //string should be the Namespace????
        public async Task<HttpClient> GetHttpClientAsync(string clientId)
        {

            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("BasicClient");
            //get token
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = await GetBearerTokenHeader(clientId);

            return client;
        }
    }
```

Because tokens expire frequently (something I have no control over when it will happen), I want to reset the Token Header and retrying the call on a 401 status response, so I'm using a custom HttpMessageHandler to do just this:

`services.AddHttpClient("BasicClient").AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy()).AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenFreshnessHandler>();`

TokenFreshnessHandler class:

```
public class TokenFreshnessHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public TokenFreshnessHandler()
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                //REFRESH TOKEN AND SEND AGAIN!!!
                request.Headers.Authorization = await GetBearerTokenHeader(/** CLIENT ID  CANNOT BE RETRIEVED**/);
                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately, by the time I get a chance to reset the token header, I have no way of knowing the original ClientID parameter

Is there an effective way of making my ClientID accessible to the HTTPRequestMessage?

Can I somehow use my HTTPClient to pass some values into the Options property of an HTTPRequest message?

Comment: I'd like to suggest to add the clientId as a http-header and then get this header in the handler. Inside the handler, check for this clientId header, add the authorization and than remove the header.

Comment: Hey Bruno, thanks for the idea, I thought of that, too, but it's a bit "hacky", I was hoping there's a better way to do it, or even another approach entirely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing data from one `DelegatingHandler` to another in regards to a `HttpRequestMessage`, use the `Options`  property.

But when passing data from one Polly policy to another (wrapped by use of `PolicyWrap` or chained policies on the `HttpClient`), then you should use Polly's `Context` feature. This can be done through a convenient extension method.

In your *host setup* code:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IHttpService, HttpService>()
        .AddPolicyHandler(_ => Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.HandleResult(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                                                          .RetryAsync(1))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

Your *HTTP service* that wraps an HTTP client:

```
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public HttpService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<ApiResponse?> GetResource()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://myurl.com");

        return await Get<ApiResponse>(request);
    }

    private async Task<TResponse?> Get<TResponse>(HttpRequestMessage request)
        where TResponse : class
    {
        request.SetPolicyExecutionContext(new Context { ["clientId"] = "myClientId" });

        var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var response = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TResponse>(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

        return response;
    }
}

public interface IHttpService
{
    Task<ApiResponse?> GetResource();
}

public class ApiResponse { }
```

Your `AuthorizationMessageHandler` that ensures that the token is always set on the request message:

```
public class AuthorizationMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisitionService _tokenAcquisitionService;

    public AuthorizationMessageHandler(ITokenAcquisitionService tokenAcquisitionService)
    {
        _tokenAcquisitionService = tokenAcquisitionService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var context = request.GetPolicyExecutionContext();
        var clientId = context?["clientId"] as string ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("No clientId found in execution context");

        var token = await _tokenAcquisitionService.GetToken(clientId);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The interface for a service that acquires an *authorization token*:

```
public interface ITokenAcquisitionService
{
    Task<string> GetToken(string clientId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is indeed something that would work in a lot of cases, but in my situation, I also need to pass my HTTP Client as argument to other libraries... I was thinking I could create a dummy class which inherits HTTPClient and also contains in a property the HTTPClient created by IHTTPClientFactory. This way, I can override SendAsync and store the ClientID in my new class and use it there. But essentially, I'd have to instantiate the base constructor of the new class with a "DummyHandler" and sneakly pass all requests to a new client, which is an unfortunate design.

Comment: I'd really appreciate any feedback on the idea above. From what I read about HTTPClients, I think it would work, but from a best practices perspective, it feels like a hack :)

Comment: I believe that if your approach requires you to pass around the same client to other services then there's a flaw in your design. An `HttpClient` is simply a wrapper around a pipeline of message handlers. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm constrained to use a library which requires me to pass these http clients as parameters (at one time I will have several ClientIDs that might require an HTTPClient). They are used only for a short amount of time and they can be disposed afterwards, thus the IHTTPClientFactory seems to be an ideal choice, but this lack of configuration is a bit blocking

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some ways to do that, of course, without changing the request.

But it all depends on how you are going to use that `HttpClientService`and how it is registered in the `DI`.

So for example, you could have a "session" object in the `DI` which is registered as singleton, but the value is treated as local, so that you could use a factory to get the most updated version of it.

```
public class ClientSession
{ 
    private AsyncLocal<string> clientId { get; set; }
    public string? ClientId 
    { 
        get => this.clientId?.Value; 
        set => this.clientId?.Value = value; 
    }
}

public class ClientSessionFactory : IClientSessionFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public ClientSessionFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    
    public ClientSession Create()
    {
        return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClientSession>();
    }
}
```

So, this factory can be injected inside the `HttpHandler`:

```
private readonly IClientSessionFactory ClientSessionFactory;

public TokenFreshnessHandler(IClientSessionFactory ClientSessionFactory)
{
    this.ClientSessionFactory = ClientSessionFactory;
}

protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var clientSession = ClientSessionFactory.Create();
}
```

And you can set the `client id` before create your client:

```
var clientSession = ClientSessionFactory.Create();
clientSession.ClientId = "xpto";
var httpClient = httpClientService.GetHttpClientAsync();
```

That's the idea.

Also, you could adapt it to use like this:

```
using (var clientSession = ClientSessionFactory.Create())
{
    clientSession.ClientId = "xpto";
    var httpClient = httpClientService.GetHttpClientAsync();
}
```

But then you have to implement some disposing mechanism.

Comment: Hey Bruno, interesting thought, but would this be a problem if I try to use 2 HTTPClients in the same await context?